# bug in a table creation using smo

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, exception, c#-4.0, smo

I am trying to create a simple table `testtable` using SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) in a winforms application.

```
Database db = srv.Databases["model"];
Table t = new Table(db,"testtable");

DataType dt = new DataType(SqlDataType.Int);
Column c = new Column(t, "ID", dt);
c.Nullable = false;
t.Columns.Add(c);

dt = new DataType(SqlDataType.VarChar, 100);
c = new Column(t, "Name", dt);
t.Columns.Add(c);

try
{
    Index i = new Index(t, "PK");
    IndexedColumn ic = new IndexedColumn(i, "ID");
    i.IndexedColumns.Add(ic);
    i.IndexKeyType = IndexKeyType.DriPrimaryKey;
    i.Create();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
}
```

but each time it shows

> Create failed for Index PK ?

Comment: and the code doesn't create any table at the SQL server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was missing.. `table.create()`.. problem is solved.